# Call App's forceUpdate in a non react component without passing App as property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a module which is not a react component (let's call it A) but its variables get displayed by react. Now A has to call the forceUpdate function of App.js. But I don't want to pass always App.js as a property when I create a new object of A.

I've created following:

App.js:

```
let forceUpdateCaller;

export default class App extends React.Component {

    static forceUpdate = () => {
        if (forceUpdateCaller) {
            forceUpdateCaller();
        }
    }

    forceUpdateCaller = () => {
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        

        forceUpdateCaller = this.forceUpdateCaller;
    }

    ...

}
```

A:

```
import App from "../App";

export default class A extends ...{

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    updateContent = () => {

        ...

        App.forceUpdate();
    }
}
```

But I'm sure, there's a better, cleaner way. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `forceUpdateCaller = this.forceUpdateCaller.bind(this);`   But to make this more complete it might be better to do ->  `this.forceUpdateCaller = this.forceUpdateCaller.bind(this);  forceUpdateCaller  = this.forceUpdateCaller;`  So that internal methods also have the correct this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best way:

```
export let ref;

class App extend React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        ref = this;
    }
}
```

Now I have full access to the App object when I import `{ref}`. :)